# Azure service bus relay converts 204 'No Content' responses into 502 'Bad Gateway'

Tags: wcf, azure, azure-servicebusrelay

I have an Azure service bus relay that exposes an on-premise service to external clients.  If I hit the on-premise service directly with a particular request (a REST request for resource that doesn't exist), I get a 'HTTP/1.1 204 No Content' response which I like.

When the same request is fired via the Azure relay, a 'HTTP/1.1 502 Bad Gateway' which I don't like because the client code treats this as an error (whereas it silently ignores a 204).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try using Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll version 2.3 with Azure SDK 2.3

Comment: Thanks, but we are already using 2.4.  I will think about 2.5 though, it might be worth trying.

Answer (score 0):

An ugly way could be manually redirecting the non-existing content to a custom 204 message page, haven't tested this and best case would be a temporary solution until you can get the proper response to work.

Comment: There is no web page, this is service / api.